# Update file (overwrite) file if file in other directory has changed. Simple Makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a file `dir/a.txt` which is updated occasionally. When I run `make` I need to update a file in the current directory `a.txt` such that it is overwritten with `dir/a.txt` if the latter has changed. I tried this

```
all: a.txt
    cp dir/a.txt a.txt

a.txt: dir/a.txt
```

but this will always update `a.txt`, whether it has changed or not. In this simple case, it does not matter much if the file is updated with a new modification time stamp, but I would like to learn how to use `make` to only update the file if `dir/a.txt` has changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do it like this:

```
.PHONY: all

all: a.txt

a.txt: dir/a.txt
    cp $< $@
```

Your mistake is in writing the recipe

```
cp dir/a.txt a.txt
```

for a target, `all`, that will never be created, so the recipe
will always be executed. That target is in fact [phony](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html),
and (btw) you should tell `make` that it is:

```
.PHONY: all
```